# Looking for stats on tablet usage in a specific demographic

Tags: research, tablet, demographics

My team is curious about what devices our primary users use in their spare time. Polling our users isn't easy for us. I'd rather find existing studies that have polled the same demographics as our primary user base.

I'd like to know what kinds of devices (specifically tablets) white men aged 30 - 50 who earn around $75K use. If the data varies by region, I'm looking for the suburban Midwest.

Do any such studies exist?

Answer (score 1):

I think your company will greatly benefit from using [Google planning tools](https://www.thinkwithgoogle.com/tools/).

You may also find some use of [this article](http://www.smartinsights.com/mobile-marketing/mobile-marketing-analytics/mobile-marketing-statistics/).